# Multitouch Gestures on 15" retina macbookpro and ubuntu 13

Tags: 13.04, touchpad, multi-touch, macbook-pro

How do i enable multitouch gestures like pinch & zoom, three fingers drag, 4 fingers swipe (basically what osx has) in ubuntu 13 on 15" retina macbookpro?

The basic 1 tap for clicking and 2 fingers to scroll work Ok for me.

A few articles exist for multitouch gestures in ubuntu 12, but nothing convincing for ubuntu 13.

Answer (score 0):

Install [touchegg](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg)

its in the repositories, so just go:

```
 sudo apt-get install touchegg
```

since its a terminal program you can run it directly from terminal to "test" gestures
It allows moves like three finger swipe , pinch etc.